# How to get the ContractRef from AccountId or codehash with Ink!

Tags: polkadot, ink, smart-contract, cross-contract-call

From the ink! cross-contract docs, contract references give developers a **type-safe** way of interacting with a contract. However, this is not only available when the contract is already instantiated.

My question is, given the `AccountId` or code hash of the contract, is there a way to convert that to a `ContractRef` so I'm sure that `AccountId` really points to a contract with the expected type?

Currently, ink! has the `CallBuilder` but this doesn't ensure the contract is of the expected type.
For instance, supposed I've 3 contracts. The first contract has the main struct named `First`, the second `Second`, and the third `Third`. Assume both `First` and `Second` has a method called `flip`. Within the `Third` contract, if I want to call the `flip` method from the *already instantiated* `First` contract, implementing it would be:

```rust
let my_return_value = build_call::<DefaultEnvironment>()
    .call(contracts_address)
    .gas_limit(0)
    .transferred_value(10)
    .exec_input(
        ExecutionInput::new(Selector::new(ink::selector_bytes!("flip")))
            .push_arg(42u8)
    )
    .returns::<bool>()
    .invoke();
```

However this doesn't ensure only the `First` contract's flip method is called. Using the `Second` contract's address would also work.

Answer (score 2):

From the snippet you gave, it looks like you want to *call* a contract, not create it. You can't convert `CodeHash` into a `ContractRef` b/c they're different things. `CodeHash` represents the code of the contract lives, not an address of a specific *instance* of the contract.

To turn an `AccountId` into a specific contract ref, you can follow the example given here https://github.com/Cardinal-Cryptography/bulletin-board-example/blob/main/contracts/bulletin_board/lib.rs#L497-L504

Comment: Thanks. But actually this doesn't really answer my question. From the reference you gave, from_account_id just wraps the account_id in the ContractRef without any checks and eventuality a method call behaves just like the snippet I gave in my question

Comment: Yes, that's the point of `ContractRef` - it gives you a type-safe information about available methods (args, return types) of the contract you want to call. There's nothing more you can do - `AccountId` itself has no information about the contract that lives under that address so you, as a developer, has to define what type (contract) you're expecting to talk to.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot obtain ContractRef from code-hash or AccountId but you may determine whether a given function (function selector; to be precise) exists at a given address to some extend by using `try_invoke` rather than `invoke` (Not the best way though :p).

Bonus: You can also look at ERC165 to know more ways to tackle this kind of problem.

P.S: If a contract supports wildcard selector then this may not hold true.